# Migrate a unhosted SVN Repo to GIT

Tags: git, svn, bitbucket, git-svn

I have a SVN repository (1.6GB in size) which has just been provided to me by my client. The repository is not hosted and has been provided to me in a ZIP file format. How can I convert this to a GIT-BitBucket repo ?

All the answers I have found for migrating SVN to GIT needs the SVN repository to be hosted somewhere and then using svn git perform the migration, but this is just a zip file I have. I also want to maintain the history of commits and branches if possible.

What would be the best way to do this ?

Comment: Were you provided the actual repository, or were you provided with a checkout?

Comment: The actual repository which was in the form of a ZIP file which had the trunk, branches, tags folder

Answer (score 1):

You can host the svn on your own computer and then do the conversion instructions normally. The url for the server would then start with `file://` instead of normal `http://` or any similliar protocol

Comment: I have tried using VisualSVN Server to host my repository locally, but when I try to import the repository to the server it says "Invalid Repository, please enter a valid repository path" even though I point it to a folder which has the .svn folder in there.

Comment: If the zip only contains the working copy (probably has a .svn folder) then you don't have enough data to convert it to git format. You don't have the whole history of commits, only the data needed to contact the SVN server for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, you said that you have the repository itself, with the "trunk, branches, tags" folder. That is a checkout of the repository, not the actual repository. The root directory of a repository looks more like this:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 svn svn 4096 Sep 29  2005 conf/
drwxrwsr-x  2 svn svn 4096 Sep 29  2005 dav/
drwxrwsr-x  6 svn svn 4096 Jun 23 02:31 db/
drwxr-xr-x  2 svn svn 4096 Jun 23 07:09 hooks/
drwxrwsr-x  2 svn svn 4096 Sep 29  2005 locks/
drwxr-sr-x  7 svn svn 4096 Feb  7  2008 tags/
-r--r--r--  1 svn svn  379 Sep 29  2005 README.txt
-r--r--r--  1 svn svn    2 Sep 29  2005 format
```

And the README.txt says something like this:

```
This is a Subversion repository; use the 'svnadmin' tool to examine
it.  Do not add, delete, or modify files here unless you know how
to avoid corrupting the repository.

If the directory "db" contains a Berkeley DB environment,
you may need to tweak the values in "db/DB_CONFIG" to match the
requirements of your site.

Visit http://subversion.tigris.org/ for more information.
```

If you don't have that, then you don't have the repository.

(If it matters, the above is from a Subversion 1.8 repo, format 3.)